# Prolog transform and separate term (atom) into a list

Tags: list, prolog

I have a term (more accurately an atom) like this: 
`name1(value1),name2(value2)` 
and I would like to have instead a "real" list like this: 
`[name1(value1), name2(value2)]`
or separeted terms like this: 
`name1(value1)` and `name2(value2)` 
any idea on how to do it?

Comment: better you know what you are speaking about...If you don't understand your problem how we could ?

Comment: noted, although I think it was pretty clear.

Comment: the comma it's 'overloaded' in Prolog, and it's the 'main' connective available, as well as a separator. Thus you must be clear the context... where `name1(value1),name2(value2)` lives.

Comment: `name1(value1),name2(value2)` is an unique element of a list that I have. so if my list is [H|T] the head would be the entire `name1(value1),name2(value2)` and the tail would be []. that's why I would like to transform it into a list with head `name1(value1)` and tail `name2(value2)`, dealing with that comma that is causing me the problem

Comment: If the tail is name2(value2), then the term you are talking about is not a list: You only call it a list if its tail is a list, and name2(value2) is not a list.

Comment: I didn't say name2(value2) was a list nor a tail. I said I would like to separate it from name1(value1) and transform all into a list with Head name1(value1) and Tail name2(value2)

Comment: You just said it again: "TAIL name2(value2)", and I say again: if the tail is "name2(value2)", then the whole term cannot be a list. For it to be a list, the tail would have to be the LIST [name2(value2)].

Comment: that's what I meant, excuse me for not putting the brackets, but it was also very clear the tail I wanted. I'll try to be completely accurate from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
ands((A,B)) --> !, ands(A), ands(B).
ands(X)     --> [X].
```

Example:

```
?- phrase(ands((a,b,c,d)), Ls).
Ls = [a, b, c, d].
```

Comment: for your example works, but not for mine, as later I try to do a listsplit([H|T], H, T). to test it, and the result is the same not splitted term in the Head `name1(value1),name2(value2)` (the Tail empty of course)

Comment: Then the term is not what you say it is. (name1(value1),name2(value2)) is a term with functor ',' and two arguments, you can also write it as ','(name1(value1),name2(value2)), and the code I posted works for this term. You can inspect your terms with arg/3, functor/3, (=..)/2 and write_canonical/1, please make sure they are what you think.

Comment: if I do write_canonical(It) the given result is `'name1(value1),name2(value2)'` so it's an atom.

Comment: Then use term_to_atom/2 to first convert the atom to a structure: Example: ?- term_to_atom(T, 'name1(value1),name2(value2)'). Yielding: T = (name1(value1), name2(value2)), and then you can use the code I posted to convert this so called "and-list" to a list.

Comment: ok, now it works, that was the predicate I needed, I was already thinking on how to parse the atom to do the split, but way lot easier with this. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: mat, would you like us to merge all of your unregistered accounts into one so you can associate an OpenID with it? This would mean unlocking quite a few privileges with their combined reputation. Flag this answer if so, or provide an answer to [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124445/user-merge-request)

Answer (score 1):

In Prolog we use pattern matching to apply different processing to list'elements:

```
change_list([], []).  % end of recursion
change_list([(T1,T2)|Ri], [T1,T2|Ro]) :-  % recursive step doing required transformation
  !, change_list(Ri, Ro).
change_list([E|Ri], [E|Ro]) :-  % catch all rule: copy elem
  change_list(Ri, Ro).
```

Comment: that doesn't work either. I do again the test listsplit([H|T], H, T). and the head is still the same `name1(value1),name2(value2)`. could it be because is considering the whole term as a string and therefore the comma as a character (ascii 44)?

Comment: what happens in your prolog if you try `?- (a,b) = (X,Y).`  ??

Comment: the usual `X = a, Y = b.` but with my program I'm not using the console for output, instead I'm printing a web with the results.

Answer (score 1):

simple: for your list `[H|T]` with `T=[]` and `H` the compound term in question that is its head element, have `H=','(A,B), List=[A,B]`.

You can even just write `H=(A,B), List=[A,B].` - parentheses are mandatory here.

IOW the data term you're talking about is just an ordinary compound term, with ',' as its functor. If you don't know the structure of these terms in advance, you can inspect it with `=../2':

```
H =.. [Functor | Arguments].
```

(I see you got the same advice from @mat).

Comment: I think is not a compound term, I've checked it with write_canonical, and it gives me `'name1(value1),name2(value2)'` so I think it's an atom.

Comment: check it with `H =.. X`, does it give you a list `X=[',' | _A]`, with ',' as its head element ? If so, ',' is the functor of the compound term under `H`. `_A` will be a list of "arguments" of the compound term. It seems `write_canonical` in your implementation plays tricks on you. What implementation are you using?

Comment: or, just try `?- H=(A,B).`, as suggested in the answer. Does it succeed? If so, this is indeed a compound term because `(A,B)` is a compound term, with ',' its functor, and `[A,B]` its arguments list. Or just try `?- atom(H).` Does it say "No"? There's a hint that it is not an atom. When I try `?- atom( (1,2) ).` in SWI Prolog, the answer is `No`.

Comment: it was definitely an atom, so mat's comment was the one. thank you